# Py2neo OGM create relationship with properties

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

From the example of py2neo site:
http://py2neo.org/v3/ogm.html

class Movie(GraphObject):

```
__primarykey__ = "title"

title = Property()
tag_line = Property("tagline")
released = Property()

actors = RelatedFrom("Person", "ACTED_IN")
directors = RelatedFrom("Person", "DIRECTED")
producers = RelatedFrom("Person", "PRODUCED")
```

class Person(GraphObject):

```
__primarykey__ = "name"

name = Property()
born = Property()

acted_in = RelatedTo(Movie)
directed = RelatedTo(Movie)
produced = RelatedTo(Movie)
```

Is there a way to specify properties for the relationship ? 
eg. i want to add weighting for the relationship.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having instantiated a `p = Person()` object, this is the output of `help(p.acted_in.add)`:

````
Signature: p.acted_in.add(obj, properties=None, **kwproperties)
Docstring:
Add a related object.

:param obj: the :py:class:`.GraphObject` to relate
:param properties: dictionary of properties to attach to the relationship (optional)
:param kwproperties: additional keyword properties (optional)
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/ogm.py
Type:      method```
````

So, if you have a `m = Movie()` object instantiated, you can call e.g.

```
p.acted_in.add(m, properties={"weight": 0.74})
```